# Bayeux/CometD C Lang Client

Tags: java, c, websocket, bayeux

I'am trying to connect a WebRTC C client to a Java Server under CometD through Websocket.

The problem is that, it is not possible to use regular websocket libraries like "Libwebsockets" to handshake the Java Bayeux Server.

Is there any C library that allows us to handshake a Bayeux Server or let us make a custom handshake form ?

If not, i will have to code my own connector. 
This scenario taken into account, do you have any ideas where to start or 
what to use to allow me to make a custom handshake form in C ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Bayeux protocol is defined [here](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_bayeux).

In itself, the protocol is quite simple, and there are two implementations in the [CometD project](https://cometd.org): one in JavaScript and one in Java.

A C implementation was discussed a while back, but lacked traction, so it was never implemented.
Perhaps it won't be impossible to call the Java implementation via JNI, but of course that has its drawbacks.

You are more than welcome to discuss this in the [CometD mailing list](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_contribute_mailing_lists) or on a [CometD issue](https://bugs.cometd.org).